# Database Connection Error JDBC

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I am using Oracle Express Edition to work with a project in JAVA/SQL. The code has no compiling errors, but when I try to run it, I get an error that says:

Failed    call.XE.SYS.DBMS_FEATURE_TEST_PROC_1

Here is my code:

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.sql.*;

 public class StudentAverages {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@//host_name:port_number:SID");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from [Sheet1$]");

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();


        while (rs.next()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                if (i > 1)
                    System.out.print(", ");
                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.print(columnValue);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        st.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.print("Exception: ");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }



}
        public void StudentMean(Connection con, Statement st, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

              try{
         Statement stOne, stTwo, stThree, stFour;
         String SelectAverage = "SELECT MEAN FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsOne = stOne.executeQuery(SelectAverage);

    String TotalAverage = "SELECT Avg(MEAN) AS averages FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsTwo = stTwo.executeQuery(TotalAverage);     

          String student_stan_dev = "SELECT STDEV(MEAN) AS standardDeviation FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsThree = stThree.executeQuery(student_stan_dev);

           int onesdMean = 1;


           //Loop Duration_Sec column
           while(rsOne.next()){

           //Convert values into float values
            allAvgs = rsOne.getFloat("MEAN");
            totalAvg = rsTwo.getFloat("averages"); 
            StDev = rsThree.getFloat("standardDeviation");
           }

                    //Calculate one standard deviation away from mean  
                    theSD = allAvgs - (onesdMean * StDev);


                      //Create a new column
        String flaggedStudents = "ALTER TABLE STUDENTS ADD FlaggedStudents INT";
        ResultSet rsFour = stFour.executeUpdate(flaggedStudents);

           if(allAvgs >= theSD){

                           //Flag students who meet the criteria
               String FlagHint = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents VALUES('1')";
               st.executeUpdate(FlagHint);
           }

                    //Count the students who meet the criteria and add those students 
                    //to a new table

        String countInstances = "SELECT STUDENTS.NAME, STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents" +
                "COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENTS) AS cnt FROM STUDENTS";
           st.executeQuery(countInstances);


        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentCount" +
        "(NAME INT , cnt INT)");

        String insertVals = String.format("INSERT INTO StudentCount" +
                "(NAME , cnt INT") +
                " VALUES ('%s','%s')");

        st.execute(insertVals);
}
    catch(SQLException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

What is causing this error, and how can I get my project running? I am using a thin driver. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
Stack Trace:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at StudentAverages.main(StudentAverages.java:23)
exception :
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@//host_name:port_number:SID
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at StudentAverages.main(StudentAverages.java:31)
```

Comment: which line causes the error? please, we're not sitting beside you looking at your ide...

Comment: Please post the stacktrace messages to have a better understanding of the problem. Also, it would help to know the line number where the error arises.

Comment: There could be number of places where `Exception` can occur. My best guess would be `SQLException` for `FlagHint`. You are supposed to provide `columname` there.

Comment: It doesn't say which line causes the error. I am using eclipse and it says "Failed call.XE.SYS.DBMS_FEATURE_TEST_PROC_1" on the SQL Results Tab. That's all it says. I tried editing my post, to attach a picture of the error, but it says I need 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: I attached a snapshot of the error I'm getting.

Comment: @user2554121 When you select `Console` tab in your `eclipse`, can you see some text there? The `stacktrace` will be there.

Comment: @user2554121: Any reason you're not using the Oracle JDBC driver, as opposed to the generic ODBC driver?

Comment: @Smit, it says "No consoles to display at this time", which is an odd behavior. At one point I tried re-installing eclipse, to see if that would fix the issue, but it didn't. The ping to the Oracle connection was successful, but when I run, that error is the only thing I see. There is nothing else on the other tabs.

Comment: @Joev, I tried changing the `Class.forName` to the following: `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");` But I still get the error.

Comment: @user2554121 Without enough information its not possible to help you. I will suggest you to debug your code. If you dont know how to debug then use  [Eclipse Debugging tutorial](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)

Comment: I suggest not running this from within Eclipse- the error your seeing might not even be a problem with your code, but a problem with Eclipse (and how you configured it).  You should try running this from the command line, and see what happens.

Comment: @Joev, Just tried that. When I run it from the command line, I get `Exception: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE STUDENTS ADD FlaggedStudents **INT** 
CREATE TABLE **IF NOT EXISTS** StudentCount" + "(NAME **INT** , cnt **INT**)
INSERT INTO StudentCount" +"(NAME , cnt **INT**"
Above commands are not supossed to run on Oracle. INT datatype is not supported, IF NOT EXISTS clause is a MySql syntax. 
First correct SQL commands and check if they work on some oracle client like SQLDeveloper or Toad, then try them in your java code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and have fixed the mismatched commands (I am new to database programming and was unaware that some SQL statements are not supported by specific databases) so thank you for that! I compiled my program again using @Joev's suggestion (compiling from the command prompt). I still get the error `Exception: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` which is printed from the catch statement in my main method.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through code line by line with the debugger to find which statement throws that exception. Even better - surround each statement in try{..}catch(SQLException) and log error messages somehow (to a log file for example), using log4j or even java.itil.logger. For now your code is using e.printStackTrace(); that prints a stack trace to the console, which isn't very useful. To find the problem we must know which statement throws the error, and what is the error number/description. Exception: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver tells us nothing.

Comment: thanks. I tried your suggestion and have now posted the stack trace.

Comment: Your connection string is bad --> getConnection("jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@//host_name:port_number:SID");  try this string (example): "jdbc:oracle:thin:db_user/db_password@host_name:orcl" --> type your database user+password,hostname, orcl -is SID of my database, check what is SID of yours.  Also check if there is a proper driver in a classpath, if no, download the driver from this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try these steps

1. Check Oracle driver(ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc14.jar) is available in your project classpath.You should use ojdb6.jar when you are using Oracle 10g or 11g.
2. Change these line

   ```
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   ```

   to

   ```
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   ```
3. And also check database url pattern, see reference [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25320/getconn.htm).